# Update text field of another application on OSX

Tags: macos, cocoa, accessibility

I'm trying to control another application using the Accessibility API. In particular, I need to change the value of a text field.

I've managed to located the AXUIElement concerned. I can read the current value and write a new one. The updated value is visible in the interface.

However, the problem is that it's not taken into account - the application itself hasn't seen the change (if there's a binding then it hasn't been activated). As soon as the UI is refreshed the old value comes back.

Does anyone know how I can force the change to have an effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried sending `AXConfirm` to the text field element? (After you change the value.)

Comment: Good idea. Unfortunately it had no effect :(

Comment: Bummer, I thought that was the purpose of `AXConfirm`. The docs say `AXConfirm` "Simulates pressing Return in an element—for example, a text field."

Comment: Hmm. The problem is that the cursor isn't in the field. I can't find a way to put it in there either....

Comment: Ah, so it is: set focus to the field; change the value; send AXConfirm.  I guess that makes sense, glad it worked!